# Set next edittext when using singleline and next button

Tags: android, android-edittext

I got some fragments on screen, each got 5 `EditText` boxes. Placed in lines horizontally one, two, two. They got `setSingleLine()` so on keyboard is next button, which skip to next `EditText`.

Here is image.

> [image]

Like numbers on image shows, it skips from first line to first box in second line next to first box in third line. If next fragment is present, it skips to first box in this fragment and continue like previously. When it reaches end it just stops and close keyboard, never jump to second box in second and third line.

How to make it skip boxes as i want. 1st line > 2nd line 1st box > 2nd line 2nd box and so on.

Comment: You can upload the image's link. We will update it in your question then.

Comment: Updated with link to image

Comment: So I found solution(can you make this comment an answer?):

For purpose of 'next' button we need:

    `view1.setNextFocusDownId(idofnextbox);`
    `view21.setNextFocusDownId(idofnextbox);`
    `view22.setNextFocusDownId(idofnextbox);`
    `view31.setNextFocusDownId(idofnextbox);`

You can also use `setNextFocus(Up/Down/Left/Right)Id(viewId)` if you have trackball or something to set focus order of views.